# Why application does not run from SCREEN without delay?

Tags: gnu-screen, tty, signals, nohup, pty

Suppose we need to run application in `screen` and keep it running when `screen` exits. The following command does the job, but only if "`sleep 1`" is appended to it. Why it does not work without "`sleep 1`"?

```
screen -d -m -L sh -c 'DISPLAY=:0 nohup zenity --info --text test >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &'
```

Comment: which place do you add the sleep

Comment: @Bharat in the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a timing problem, in that `nohup` does not have time enough to disable signals before it is signaled by one of the parents.  You can see this by adding `strace -o /tmp/s -ff` in front of the `screen` command and then in one of the log files `/tmp/s.*` you see

```
...
access("/bin/nohup", X_OK)              = 0
stat("/bin/nohup", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=36696, ...}) = 0
--- SIGHUP {si_signo=SIGHUP, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
+++ killed by SIGHUP +++
```

You can simplify the startup. This works for me without the need for `&`.

```
DISPLAY=:0 screen -d -m -L nohup zenity --info --text test
```

---

Another solution seems to be to ask the parent shell to use job control. This seems to make it either disable SIGHUP to the background, or otherwise wait for the child `nohup` to be further on before exiting itself. Using `sh -cm` instead of `sh -c` on your original command should work better. For example, this works for me

```
screen -d -m -L sh -cm 'nohup zenity --info --text test >&/dev/null & echo'
```

whereas the `-c` verson does not. `bash` has a `disown` command that protects a background job from SIGHUP, if using job control, but you don't seem to need it even without `nohup` as this works too, without leaving a `screen` process running:

```
screen -d -m -L sh -cm 'zenity --info --text test >&/dev/null </dev/null & echo'
```

Comment: There are other commands in the real script after `zenity`, so it is impossible that those commands will be executed if `&` is not used.

Comment: Is there a way to add a `while` loop or something after the `&` to ensure that `nohup` had started before proceeding further?

Comment: Use nohup as the all-encompassing command, eg: `nohup sh -c 'zenity --info --text test & date >/tmp/out'`

Comment: It is impossible to get rid of `nohup.out` file if `nohup` is used as all-encompassing command, like `screen -d -m -L nohup sh -c 'date >/tmp/out'`. It would be great if `nohup` had an option like `--background` to run its command in background (without using `&`). Maybe it's worth to write about this issue to `nohup` developer(s)...

Comment: I've updated the answer with some more tests. You can try using `sh -cm` in your original test.

Comment: I found another way that works: use all-encompassing command, but instead of `nohup`, use `nohup-noout` wrapper shell script: `nohup "$@" >/dev/null 2>/dev/null` (then `nohup.out` file will not be created).

Comment: A small correction: getting rid of `nohup.out` invalidates the `-L` flag of `screen`, so instead of saving `screen`'s log with `-L`, just gobble `screen`'s log by adding `-Logfile /dev/null` and use `nohup.out` in place of former `screenlog.0`

Answer (score 0):

Using `nohup` as all-encompassing command is impossible because it does not allow to get rid of `nohup.out` without suppressing all the output, and using `nohup.out` instead of `screenlog.0` is impossible because `nohup.out` does not preserve carriage return.

Instead of using `nohup`, use shell's `trap`. So, command in OP becomes:

```
screen -d -m -L sh -c 'trap "" HUP; DISPLAY=:0 zenity --info --text test >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &'
```